# Why DirectX9 SDK example "Matrices" with Textured alpha blending showing black screen?

Tags: directx, textures, direct3d, alphablending, render-to-texture

I was trying to analyse the alpha blending through various samples given in DirectX9 SDK , i Successfully analysed for vertex alpha blending but when i tried for texture alpha blending it shows black screen on building the solution.. took reference from [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This is the code for my analysis,

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// File: Matrices.cpp
//
// Desc: Now that we know how to create a device and render some 2D vertices,
//       this tutorial goes the next step and renders 3D geometry. To deal with
//       3D geometry we need to introduce the use of 4x4 Matrices to transform
//       the geometry with translations, rotations, scaling, and setting up our
//       camera.
//
//       Geometry is defined in model space. We can move it (translation),
//       rotate it (rotation), or stretch it (scaling) using a world transform.
//       The geometry is then said to be in world space. Next, we need to
//       position the camera, or eye point, somewhere to look at the geometry.
//       Another transform, via the view matrix, is used, to position and
//       rotate our view. With the geometry then in view space, our last
//       transform is the projection transform, which "projects" the 3D scene
//       into our 2D viewport.
//
//       Note that in this tutorial, we are introducing the use of D3DX, which
//       is a set of helper utilities for D3D. In this case, we are using some
//       of D3DX's useful matrix initialization functions. To use D3DX, simply
//       include <d3dx9.h> and link with d3dx9.lib.
//
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#pragma warning( disable : 4996 ) // disable deprecated warning 
#include <strsafe.h>
#pragma warning( default : 4996 )




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global variables
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LPDIRECT3D9             g_pD3D = NULL; // Used to create the D3DDevice
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9       g_pd3dDevice = NULL; // Our rendering device
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 g_pVB = NULL; // Buffer to hold vertices

// A structure for our custom vertex type
struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
    FLOAT x, y, z;      // The untransformed, 3D position for the vertex
    DWORD color;        // The vertex color
};

// Our custom FVF, which describes our custom vertex structure
#define D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX (D3DFVF_XYZ|D3DFVF_DIFFUSE|D3DFVF_TEX0)

LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 g_pTexture;
DWORD*  m_pRGBAData;
DWORD   m_dwWidth;
DWORD   m_dwHeight;
DWORD   m_dwStage;  


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: InitD3D()
// Desc: Initializes Direct3D
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitD3D( HWND hWnd )
{
    // Create the D3D object.
    if( NULL == ( g_pD3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION ) ) )
        return E_FAIL;

    // Set up the structure used to create the D3DDevice
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof( d3dpp ) );
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;

    // Create the D3DDevice
    if( FAILED( g_pD3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd,
                                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                                      &d3dpp, &g_pd3dDevice ) ) )
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // Turn off culling, so we see the front and back of the triangle
    g_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE );

    // Turn off D3D lighting, since we are providing our own vertex colors
    g_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE );
    g_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);    // turn on the z-buffer


    return S_OK;
}




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: InitGeometry()
// Desc: Creates the scene geometry
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitGeometry()
{

    // Initialize three vertices for rendering a triangle
    CUSTOMVERTEX g_Vertices[] =
    {       
        { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(128,0,0, 255), },  //first triangle
        { 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(128,0, 0, 255), },    
        { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(128,0, 0, 255), },  

        { -0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255,0, 255, 0), },  //second triangle
        {  1.0f,-1.0f, 0.5f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255,0, 255, 0), }, 
        {  0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255,0, 255, 0), },

    };

    // Create the vertex buffer.
    if( FAILED( g_pd3dDevice->CreateVertexBuffer( 11 * sizeof( CUSTOMVERTEX ),
                                                  0, D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX,
                                                  D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &g_pVB, NULL ) ) )
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // Fill the vertex buffer.
    VOID* pVertices;
    if( FAILED( g_pVB->Lock( 0, sizeof( g_Vertices ), ( void** )&pVertices, 0 ) ) )
        return E_FAIL;
    memcpy( pVertices, g_Vertices, sizeof( g_Vertices ) );
    g_pVB->Unlock();

    return S_OK;
}




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: Cleanup()
// Desc: Releases all previously initialized objects
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
VOID Cleanup()
{
    if( g_pVB != NULL )
        g_pVB->Release();

    if( g_pd3dDevice != NULL )
        g_pd3dDevice->Release();

    if( g_pD3D != NULL )
        g_pD3D->Release();
}



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: SetupMatrices()
// Desc: Sets up the world, view, and projection transform Matrices.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
VOID SetupMatrices()
{
    // For our world matrix, we will just rotate the object about the y-axis.
    D3DXMATRIXA16 matWorld;

    // Set up the rotation matrix to generate 1 full rotation (2*PI radians) 
    // every 1000 ms. To avoid the loss of precision inherent in very high 
    // floating point numbers, the system time is modulated by the rotation 
    // period before conversion to a radian angle.
    UINT iTime = timeGetTime() % 10000;
    FLOAT fAngle = iTime * ( 2.0f * D3DX_PI ) / 10000.0f;
    D3DXMatrixRotationY( &matWorld, fAngle );
    g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld );

    // Set up our view matrix. A view matrix can be defined given an eye point,
    // a point to lookat, and a direction for which way is up. Here, we set the
    // eye five units back along the z-axis and up three units, look at the
    // origin, and define "up" to be in the y-direction.
    D3DXVECTOR3 vEyePt( 0.0f, 3.0f,-5.0f );
    D3DXVECTOR3 vLookatPt( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    D3DXVECTOR3 vUpVec( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    D3DXMATRIXA16 matView;
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH( &matView, &vEyePt, &vLookatPt, &vUpVec );
    g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_VIEW, &matView );

    // For the projection matrix, we set up a perspective transform (which
    // transforms geometry from 3D view space to 2D viewport space, with
    // a perspective divide making objects smaller in the distance). To build
    // a perpsective transform, we need the field of view (1/4 pi is common),
    // the aspect ratio, and the near and far clipping planes (which define at
    // what distances geometry should be no longer be rendered).
    D3DXMATRIXA16 matProj;
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &matProj, D3DX_PI / 4, 1.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f );
    g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj );
}



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: Render()
// Desc: Draws the scene
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
VOID Render()
{
    // Clear the backbuffer to a black color
    g_pd3dDevice->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_ARGB( 255, 0, 0, 0 ), 1.0f, 0 );
    g_pd3dDevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    // Begin the scene
    if( SUCCEEDED( g_pd3dDevice->BeginScene() ) )
    {
        // Setup the world, view, and projection Matrices
        SetupMatrices();

        // Create an alpha texture
        D3DXCreateTexture(g_pd3dDevice, 128, 128, 0,D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET, 
                D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &g_pTexture);

        // Initialize the alpha channel
        int  yGrad, xGrad;
        D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;

        if(SUCCEEDED(g_pTexture->LockRect(0, &lockedRect, NULL, D3DLOCK_DISCARD )))
        {
            m_pRGBAData = new DWORD[128*128];
            if( m_pRGBAData != NULL )
            {
                for( DWORD y=0; y < m_dwHeight; y++ )
                {   
                    DWORD dwOffset = y*m_dwWidth;
                    yGrad = (int)(((float)y/(float)m_dwWidth) * 255.0f);

                    for( DWORD x=0; x < m_dwWidth; x )
                    {
                        xGrad = (int)(((float)x/(float)m_dwWidth) * 255.0f);

                        DWORD b = (DWORD)(xGrad + (255 - yGrad))/2 & 0xFF;
                        DWORD g = (DWORD)((255 - xGrad) + yGrad)/2 & 0xFF;
                        DWORD r = (DWORD)(xGrad + yGrad)/2 & 0xFF;
                        DWORD a = (DWORD)(xGrad + yGrad)/2 & 0xFF;

                        //lockedRect.pBits[dwOffset+x] =(unsigned char*)(a<<24L)+(r<<16L)+(g<<8L)+(b);


                        unsigned char* pBytes = (unsigned char*)lockedRect.pBits; // lr = D3DLOCKED_RECT you get from locking the texture
                        unsigned int offset = y *lockedRect.Pitch + x * 4; // as explained in earlier post
                        pBytes[offset] = a; // alpha, red, green, blue are unsigned chars 0...255
                        pBytes[offset + 1] = r;
                        pBytes[offset + 2] = g;
                        pBytes[offset + 3] = b;
                        x++;
                    }
                }
            }
            g_pTexture->UnlockRect((UINT)&lockedRect);
        }

        //Render the vertex buffer contents
        //g_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
        //g_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_BLENDOP, D3DBLENDOP_MAX);

        // Assign texture
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTexture(0, g_pTexture);

        // Texture stage states
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);  

        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);

        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);

        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);


        g_pd3dDevice->SetStreamSource( 0, g_pVB, 0, sizeof( CUSTOMVERTEX ) );
        g_pd3dDevice->SetFVF( D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX );
        g_pd3dDevice->DrawPrimitive( D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST,2 ,11 );

        // End the scene
        g_pd3dDevice->EndScene();
    }

    // Present the backbuffer contents to the display
    g_pd3dDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
}




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: MsgProc()
// Desc: The window's message handler
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT WINAPI MsgProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( msg )
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            Cleanup();
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: WinMain()
// Desc: The application's entry point
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
INT WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, INT )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( hInst );

    // Register the window class
    WNDCLASSEX wc =
    {
        sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ), CS_CLASSDC, MsgProc, 0L, 0L,
        GetModuleHandle( NULL ), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        L"D3D Tutorial", NULL
    };
    RegisterClassEx( &wc );

    // Create the application's window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow( L"D3D Tutorial", L"D3D Tutorial 03: Matrices",
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 256, 256,
                              NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL );

    // Initialize Direct3D
    if( SUCCEEDED( InitD3D( hWnd ) ) )
    {
        // Create the scene geometry
        if( SUCCEEDED( InitGeometry() ) )
        {
            // Show the window
            ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
            UpdateWindow( hWnd );

            // Enter the message loop
            MSG msg;
            ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof( msg ) );
            while( msg.message != WM_QUIT )
            {
                if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) )
                {
                    TranslateMessage( &msg );
                    DispatchMessage( &msg );
                }
                else
                    Render();
            }
        }
    }

    UnregisterClass( L"D3D Tutorial", wc.hInstance );
    return 0;
}
```

Please provide with the solution.

Comment: "Black screen" can be caused by one zillion of issues. Use graphics debugger to check your pipeline step-by-step and find out what's wrong.

Comment: I have just written a simple code by creating multiple triangles one in front of other and debugged it several times using PIX.. It shows four triangles formed in viewport but shows black screen in output render screen..

Comment: If you didn't change anything in the Sample, it will works fine, I just tried this sample, it works fine, if you change the code, please paste the full code you have changed.

Comment: The same code is working fine when i ammended it for vertex alpha blending but shows black pixels on ammending the code for texture alpha blending.